# Fastest iteration on a dataframe by applying an url function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, iteration

I need to request some data from an url by inserting a variable=var for each row of my dataframe. I wrote a function that iterates over each row

```
def df_eval(data):
    data_eval = data.copy()
    df_price = []
    for i in data_eval.index:
        var = data_eval.at[i, 'var']
        url = ("http://blablabla/params&cid={}".format(var))
        r_json = requests.get(url).json()
        df = json_normalize(r_json)
        df_price.append(df['price'])
        print(df_price)

data_eval['price_eval'] = df_price
return data_eval
```

Could you be able to suggest a faster way for this operation. Currently it takes about 30 minutes over 23000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could paralelize your calls like this:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

data_split = np.array_split(data, n_cores)
pool = Pool(n_cores)
data = pd.concat(pool.map(df_eval, data_split))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Source: https://towardsdatascience.com/make-your-own-super-pandas-using-multiproc-1c04f41944a1